# devenv.exe hogs CPU when debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

**Short version:**
When I debug ASP.NET MVC apps in VS2013 and try to edit razor views or css files, the CPU usage of `devenv.exe` skyrockets to the point where VS becomes unresponsive. Browser link is turned off, yet this still happens. Restarting debugging doesn't help, restarting VS doesn't help, restarting windows helps only for a short while, before the problem shows up again. How do I fix this?

**Long version:**
I'm having some trouble with Visual Studio 2013. Namely, after I start debugging an ASP.NET MVC app devenv.exe starts hogging CPU (to the point where Visual Studio becomes unresponsive). Some time ago this was happening only from time to time, but now it happens nearly always.

At first I thought that it was a problem with Browser Link, but the problem didn't go away after I turned it off and closing the browser while debugging doesn't have any effect.

Stopping debugging makes it stop hogging CPU, but it doesn't make the problem go away when I debug the app next time. Restarting VS doesn't help either and restarting Windows only helps for a little while.

The main clue here is that `devenv.exe` shows low CPU usage while VS window is not active. Switching to VS window makes devenv.exe use more CPU, but trying to do anything in VS (especially editing a razor view or css file) makes the CPU usage skyrocket.

*Anyone got an idea what could be causing this problem and how to solve it?*

Being unable to edit css and views while debugging is seriously lowering my productivity (the app takes good minute or two to start).

P.S. The app I'm working on right now is a [nopcommerce](/questions/tagged/nopcommerce) based shop, but I had this problem before while debugging MVC apps that had nothing to do with nopcommerce.

Comment: Update: Closing all editor windows in VS makes devenv.exe use less CPU, but it's still having high CPU usage spikes when doing seemingly simple things (like scrolling Solution Explorer).

Comment: Try to disable any plugin that is running. Or if that doesn't work see if this occurs in a new project as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find the source of the problem, but closing all editor windows in VS seems to make it go away. If there are further lag spikes, restarting debugging might be also a good idea.

Since I didn't see this problem in a new project, it might be related to the sheer size of the solution, the number of files being opened in the editor at one time (though the problem remained even when I left one view open), the time those files where opened in the VS (I'm not entirely sure why this would be a problem, maybe it has something to do with the file history).